# C++ number theory library (thread-safe, cross-platform)

Tags: c++, thread-safety, number-theory

I'm looking for an optimized, cross-platform and **thread-safe** C/C++ library that supports long integers and polynomial arithmetic.

Functionality of [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/) and Lidia is enough, but they are not thread-safe.

I'm not sure about [Flint](http://www.flintlib.org/), it seems not to be cross-platform.

Can anybody help?

Comment: From the web-page for Flint: *FLINT is written in ANSI C and runs on many platforms*

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but I'll answer in case it helps anyone in the future.
Linbox has created a thread safe version of NTL.
I have used some of the functionality from this version (namely GF2, GF2X, GF2E and GF2EX) successfully in the past by merging changes from this version into NTL version 5.5.2

http://linalg.org/projects/linalg/log/trunk/ntl/doc/multithreading.txt?rev=20

Answer (score 1):

**NTL** is thread safe, you just need to compile it in a thread-safe manner. Configure before installing using the following command and it works fine:

```
./configure NTL_THREADS=on NTL_GMP_LIP=on
```

You'll need [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) installed in order to proceed though.